# why would a map method fail to alter an array?

Tags: javascript

I have a following simple function:

```
function shiftCase2(string) {
    temp = string.split('');
    temp.map(function(x) {
        if (x == x.toUpperCase()) {
            x = x.toLowerCase();
        }
        if (x == x.toLowerCase()) {
            x = x.toUpperCase();
        }
    })
    temp = temp.join("");
    console.log(temp);
}
```

It is supposed to go over each element of an array, and if character is uppercase, change it to lowercase and vice-versa. For example `shiftCase2("TEST string to USE");` should give me back `"test STRING TO use"`.

I cannot figure out why it does not work and just returns my input back to me unmodified?

Comment: `.map()` create a new array

Comment: There has to be a dupetarget for this...

Comment: `x` is a character (basic type) so it's passed by **value** not by **reference**. Plus this is not the usecase of `map` (`map` callback should return new items to be stored in a new array as result).

Comment: Your assumption seems to be that `x` will be some sort of reference to the original string, which can then be updated to change its original value. In JS, assignment is done by copying the value (which is sometimes a reference type), so assigning to a variable will never update anything except that variable.

Comment: ...and you don't need the second `if` statement, since if `x == x.toUpperCase()` failed, we know the second will pass, since each string is a single character.

Comment: To all the downvoters: Be nice http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a so called pure function. This means that it will not modify your input, instead, it will generate a new output.

You have to do like this:

```
temp = temp.map(function(x) {
    if (x == x.toUpperCase()) {
        return x.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (x == x.toLowerCase()) {
        return x.toUpperCase();
    }
})
```

I recommend checking out the [docs to learn how it works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Thanks, I understand this a lot better now. Confusion came from misunderstanding the "Array.prototype.map() creates a new array" part.  BTW. Stackoverflow is very toxic to new members.

Comment: @Milan: Toxic? You just received a page full of information from multiple users.

Comment: ...and you've been a member for almost 5 years!

Comment: And immediately got -5 as well as a "reward" for asking. Also "signed up" != member.

Comment: @Milan: I don't know why people down voted, except that it would seem that reading docs and following examples would have brought you to a solution. Ignore the votes, both up and down. They're meaningless.

Comment: @Milan I totally agree about the toxic reaction. Your question is a good one; there is a subtle and important distinction between forEach() and map() that is obvious once you learn it, but confusing before you do. Some people on here have been programming for so long, they forget what it was like when they were first starting. Don't let it get you down, and don't give up. Programming can be really fun and rewarding.

Answer (score 0):

`.map()` creates a new array. The function you pass to `.map()` must also return a new value. This is how it's done:

```
temp = temp.map(function(x) {
    if (x == x.toUpperCase()) {
        x = x.toLowerCase();
    }
    if (x == x.toLowerCase()) {
        x = x.toUpperCase();
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Much appreciated.

Comment: The whole point of map is to return a new array. It is a better practice to rename the new variable being created from 'temp' to 'swappedCase' or something more descriptive.

Comment: In general, yes. But the original purpose was to alter the temp array.

Answer (score 0):

> Array.prototype.map() creates a new array with the results of calling
>   a provided function on every element in this array. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Basically `.map()` won't modify the original input by design.

Answer (score -1):

The `.map()` method does not modify the array, it returns a new one.  However, the `.forEach()` method does mutate the array, which is what you were expecting.

Fans of code clarity and "functional programming" will say it's better to use the `.map()` method for better understanding of your code, and I generally agree. However, if performance is your main concern for large arrays, `forEach` is actually faster. See [this link](https://jsperf.com/map-vs-foreach-on-so/3) for performance comparisons. In this case, it's probably best to stick with `.map()`.

Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't add any new information that the two existing answers don't already present and is quite vague/doesn't cover all problems.

Comment: Actually, @AndrewLi, it does add new information: it mentions the .forEach() method which the other answers don't. 

By the way, if you check the time tags I was typing this answer as the other answers were posted. Perhaps you should be more careful before being so condescending to someone who was trying to be helpful.

Thanks for the comment and downvote, it's a lovely culture you're cultivating here on SO.

Comment: I'm not trying to be condescending, I'm trying to rate content and use the site as it is intended to be used. My comment was to tell you that this answer was a bit vague and had no explanation like the others and was thus not as useful, and I used my vote to reflect my opinion. I also felt like it gave bad advice (don't use forEach to mutate the array being iterated over, that's what map is for!). If you would like to edit your answer into something that adds new information, I'd be happy to revaluate my vote.

Comment: I updated it. Mentioning forEach(), a built in method that performed the operation @Milan expected in the first place, is worthy of a downvote? And map() is not for mutating an array...

Comment: IMHO I don't think forEach is suited here. forEach is for iterating over the array and using the values to do something else. map transforms values of the array, which is what the OP wants - inverting the case of the elements of the array. I'd personally take good practice over performance because I would say using what a method is intended for is better, but thanks for adding to the answer.